# i want convert factor to date, the factor is like that :2011-05-05:16:30:04.466

Tags: r

I tried with both the lubricate package and `as.Date()`, but both show error:

```
# the factor
> x
[1] '2011-05-05:16:30:04.466   '
873 Levels: '2011-05-05:16:30:04.466   ' ... '2017-08-10:20:05:51.406967'

# try 1
> as.Date(x, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
[1] NA

# try 2
> xx <- mdy(x)
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 

> xx
[1] NA

> xx <- mdy_hms(x)
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

someone can help me?

Comment: Use `anytime::anytime()` (for `POSIXct`) or `anytime::anydate()` (for `Date`) as they will first convert from `factor` to `character` for you.

Comment: Also `lubridate::ymd_hms(factor("2011-05-05:16:30:04.466"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem might be the format.  The default format in as.Date is "%Y-%m-%d" which seems to take care of the example.

```
> as.Date(as.factor('2011-05-05:16:30:04.466   '), format = "%m/%d/%Y")
[1] NA
> as.Date(as.factor('2011-05-05:16:30:04.466   '))
[1] "2011-05-05"
> as.Date(as.factor('2011-05-05:16:30:04.466   '), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "2011-05-05"
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answer by Jason Clark, there is also `as.POSIXct`, if you want to keep the times.

```
getOption("digits.secs")
#NULL

options(digits.secs = 6)

x <- factor('2011-05-05:16:30:04.466')
y <- as.POSIXct(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%OS")
y
#[1] "2011-05-05 16:30:04.466 BST"

class(y)
#[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```